# Why God Punished Egypt as per Jeremiah 46?

Tags: jeremiah, egypt

Why God Punished Egypt. Is it because they killed good king Josiah. If he was a good king, God never allows that to happen.
Also as per verse 26 it says,  "But later on, people will live in Egypt again, as they did in times past."
Though Egypt worships idols, why God is allowing them to live later and not the same happens with Israel.
Also God mentions Egypt as 'my people' as per Isaiah 19:25-- I will bless you, Egypt, my people".

My question is on what basis God is punishing Idol-worshiping countries.

Answer (score 1):

Holy Books are designed according to Divine Philosophy. If we supposed that the world  exists since about 5000 years, and Human  mentality  and psychology develops by time, then we surely suppose that O.T and N.T to be taken literally. But that is not the case.

The Humanity cannot develop in essence. I mean what is spiritual, was spiritual, and will last  spiritual. What is psychic  (soulish), was soulish, and will last soulish.  And the same for the bodily. And the same for the Mentality.

Development be in a range  from  10% to 30%. How we accept  logically  that a daughter  makes  her Father drunk to get pregnant?

Thus the matter is: How to deal with the Bible?, we should  deal with  it Literally  or Alligorically?

It is so easy:

- O.T: 80% Alligorically, 20% literally.
- N.T: 80% Literally, 20% Alligorically.

Thus, the problem  had been solved, all Peoples and Nations are God's  Sons. All People  and Nations  will be Saved lastly. God has a good plan for each People  and Nation.

God implants Collective Consciousness, Collective Unconsciousness and Collective Sentiment  for each People and Nation. That's why God punishes or rewards a People or a Nation for a while.

I hope my words was clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Why God Punished Egypt as per Jeremiah 46?**

Nebuchadnezzar received Egypt’s wealth as his pay for military service rendered in  God's execution of judgment against Tyre, an opposer of God’s people.​

Recommend reading Ezekiel chapters 29 and 30 for the complete prophecy against Egypt.

> **18 Son of man, Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon caused his army to serve
> a great service against *Tyrus:* every head was made bald, and every
> shoulder was peeled: yet had he no wages, nor his army, for *Tyrus,* for
> the service that he had served against it:19 Therefore thus saith the
> Lord God; Behold, I will give the land of Egypt unto Nebuchadrezzar
> king of Babylon;** and he shall take her multitude, and take her spoil,
> and take her prey; and it shall be the wages for his army.20 I have
> given him the land of Egypt for his labour wherewith he served against
> it, because they wrought for me, saith the Lord God

Ezekiel 30:10-12  (KJV)

> 10 Thus saith the Lord God; I will also make the multitude of Egypt to
> cease by the hand of Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon. 11 He and his
> people with him, the terrible of the nations, shall be brought to
> destroy the land: and they shall draw their swords against Egypt, and
> fill the land with the slain. 12 And I will make the rivers dry, and
> sell the land into the hand of the wicked: and I will make the land
> waste, and all that is therein, by the hand of strangers: I the Lord
> have spoken it.